# PHP Uploader - Problemas con UploadDir option

Tags: php, jquery

Hola y gracias de antemano por la ayuda ;)

Estoy usando el plugin https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer, para PHP Uploader, y en /php/class.uploader.php estoy intentando cambiar la ruta en la que hare los uploads de los ficheros:

```html
    private function initialize($field, $options){
  if(is_array($field) && in_array($field, $_FILES)){
   $this->field = $field;
            $this->field['Field_Name'] = array_search($field, $_FILES);
            $this->field['Field_Type'] = 'input';

            if(!is_array($this->field['name'])){
            $this->field = array_merge($this->field, array("name" => array($this->field['name']), "tmp_name"=>array($this->field['tmp_name']), "type"=>array($this->field['type']), "error"=>array($this->field['error']), "size"=>array($this->field['size'])));
            }

            foreach($this->field['name'] as $key=>$value){ if(empty($value)){ unset($this->field['name'][$key]); unset($this->field['type'][$key]); unset($this->field['tmp_name'][$key]); unset($this->field['error'][$key]); unset($this->field['size'][$key]); } }

            $this->field['length'] = count($this->field['name']);
  }elseif(is_string($field) && $this->isURL($field)){
            $this->field = array("name" => array($field), "size"=>array(), "type"=>array(), "error"=>array());
            $this->field['Field_Type'] = 'link';
            $this->field['length'] = 1;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        if($options != null){
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
  $varuser='test';
  //$varuser=$_SESSION['username'];
  $this->options['uploadDir']="../../../uploads/".$varuser."/";
  
  return $this->prepareFiles();
    }
```

Como podeis ver, al final de la funcion estoy declarando la "option" UploadDir como la concatenación de "../../../uploads/" + $varuser +"/", usando el lcodigo tal como esta (es decir con $varuser='test') todo funciona correctamente.

Pero, mi problema empieza cuando intento asignar la variable de sesion en la que guardo el usuario conectado, si uso el modo debugador en Chrome me relaciona el error con la siguiente referencia: custom.js:91 (/examples/dragdrop/js)

Por favor, alguien sabe que esta pasando? Por que no puedo asignar la variable de sesion pero si una variable definida "a mano"?

Muchisimas gracias!
Un saludo.

Comment: This is the spanish site. Please, write your question in spanish or move it to stackoverflow.com

Comment: Perdon, culpa mia, queda traducido a espanol. Un saludo!

Comment: No te preocupes. Ya he abierto el proceso para reabrirla.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a enfocarnos en la siguiente linea:

```
$varuser='test';
//$varuser=$_SESSION['username'];
```

y principalmente en $_SESSION ([documentación 1](http://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php), [documentación 2](http://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php)), en la que indica que previamente debe existir un inicio de sesion.

```
<?php
     session_start();     
     $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
    ?>
```

Ahora, o inicias sesión, envías otro parámetro en el post o lo envías como parte del nombre de archivo

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la sesion esta iniciada desde el php "padre" al que llamo. Acabo de probar a hacer un echo por pantalla y me muestra sin problema el usuario conectado.

Crees que podria ser alguna otra cosa?

Gracias!

Comment: Por si puede servir de ayuda, para probar si el problema se replicaba en cualquier version base del plugin https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer lo he vuelto a descargar, anadido a XAMPP y simplemente he intentado hacer lo mismo que explico en el mensaje, asignar una variable definida en otro lugar (en el index por ejemplo) a la concatenacion de uploadDir, y siempre falla...espero que pueda dar alguna pista ;) Gracias de nuevo

Comment: no he revisado mucho tu código, pero quizás debas validar que exista la carpeta del usuario y si no existe crearla.
            if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
                mkdir("uploads/" .$varuser. "/", 0777, true);
            }

Comment: Dentro del codigo que tiene el plugin ya esta manejando la situacion de no existir la carpeta para crearla. en la cariable que defino como varuser, puedo asignarle cualquier valor y funciona el proceso, solo falla cuando intento asignarle una variable definida en otra parte del codigo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En la definición de la incialización de la clase está parte de la respuesta:

```
private function initialize($field, $options){
```

que se completa cerca de donde estas modificando las options a mano

```
    if($options != null){
        $this->setOptions($options);
    }
```

Así que para evitar contextos extraños donde `$_SESSION`no está definida pásale las options al crear la instancia:

```
<?php
 session_start();   
 $varuser=$_SESSION['username'];
 $rutaUploads = "../../../uploads/".$varuser."/"; // <- ajusta el path 
 include('class.fileuploader.php');
 // initialize the FileUploader
 $FileUploader = new FileUploader('files', array(
    // Options will go here
    'uploadDir'=>$rutaUploads,
));
```

> al utilizar una clase de terceros siempre intenta usar los métodos provistos por dicha clase para definir opciones, de lo contrario si debes actualizar la clase por un bug o mejora no pierdes los cambios, y evitas situaciones como esta donde por el contexto variables como `$_SESSION` pueden no estar disponibles